# Control interval for Labels on 'xAxis' in React Native Chart Kit

Tags: react-native, label, linegraph, x-axis, react-native-chart-kit

I created a Line Graph based on `react-native-chartkit` with user's weight data which changes over some period of time. I am trying to visualize the proper time interval between weight entries. Does anyone know if it is possible to control the space between labels on x Axis in order to visualize proper time gaps? Right now I am only able to display them with equal spacing